# ESM import not working with redux, Node 10.1.0

Tags: node.js, redux

```js
//index.mjs

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todoApp from './reducers'
const store = createStore(todoApp)

import {
    addTodo,
    toggleTodo,
    setVisibilityFilter,
    VisibilityFilters
  } from './actions'
  
  // Log the initial state
  console.log(store.getState())
  
  // Every time the state changes, log it
  // Note that subscribe() returns a function for unregistering the listener
  const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
    console.log(store.getState())
  )
  
  // Dispatch some actions
  store.dispatch(addTodo('Learn about actions'))
  store.dispatch(addTodo('Learn about reducers'))
  store.dispatch(addTodo('Learn about store'))
  store.dispatch(toggleTodo(0))
  store.dispatch(toggleTodo(1))
  store.dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(VisibilityFilters.SHOW_COMPLETED))
  
  // Stop listening to state updates
  unsubscribe()
```

```js
//reducers.mjs

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  ADD_TODO,
  TOGGLE_TODO,
  SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER,
  VisibilityFilters
} from './actions'
const { SHOW_ALL } = VisibilityFilter

function visibilityFilter(state = SHOW_ALL, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return action.filter
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: !todo.completed
          })
        }
        return todo
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const todoApp = combineReducers({
  visibilityFilter,
  todos
})

export default todoApp
```

```js
// actions.mjs

/*
 * action types
 */

export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
export const TOGGLE_TODO = 'TOGGLE_TODO'
export const SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER = 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER'

/*
 * other constants
 */

export const VisibilityFilters = {
  SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
  SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
  SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
}

/*
 * action creators
 */

export function addTodo(text) {
  return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
}

export function toggleTodo(index) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_TODO, index }
}

export function setVisibilityFilter(filter) {
  return { type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER, filter }
}
```

Edit- added code

I am working through the Redux Basics tutorial from the Redux docs, and am having trouble getting import to work properly.

I currently have 3 files for my todo-list app:

- **actions.mjs**
- **reducers.mjs**
- **index.mjs**

I have done an `npm init -y`, and `npm install --save redux`. I copy and pasted the source code directly from the Redux docs for all 3 files.

With the command: `node --experimental-modules index`, I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'redux' does not provide an export named 'combineReducers'
```

I would expect similar error messages for other named exports of Redux...

I have had success with refactoring back to CommonJS using `require`, `module.exports`, `.js` file extensions, and the command: `node index.js`

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . A way to replicate the problem is necessary for code-related questions.

Comment: At least show the contents of those files.  Specifically, how you are `import`ing.

Comment: See https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2614#issuecomment-330555911

Comment: Thanks @estus. I had looked at that issue before, but didn't totally understand what was said. My code works now with some destructuring, but still seems odd: this **does not** work: `import redux from 'redux'; const combineReducers = redux` and this **does**: `import redux from 'redux; const combineReducers = redux.combineReducers`

Comment: Why would `const combineReducers = redux` work? `redux` is module export object. Not `combineReducers` function. I would expect `import { combineReducers } from 'redux/es'` to work.

Comment: @estus My mistake, you are correct. When using Babel, I am used to using `import redux from 'redux'; import { combineReducers } from 'redux';` But that syntax doesn't work when using ESM, as it would with Babel. That style works when importing from a file that i have written within my project, but not from a dependency such as redux.

Comment: It's `redux/es`, not `redux`. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried `import { combineReducers } from 'redux/es'` and get the message: `{ Error: Cannot find module redux/es
    at search (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:27:12)
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:63:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:56:18)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
    at ModuleWrap.promises.module.link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:35:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:34:36) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }`

Comment: I then tried `import { combineReducers } from 'redux/es/redux'` and get the message: `file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/dev/esm-test/index.mjs:3
import { createStore } from 'redux/es/redux'
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'redux/es/redux' does not provide an export named 'createStore'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:89:21)`

Comment: well... as you can see from the message, i'm actually working in index.mjs and trying to `import { createStore }` but the error is the same in the case of both `{ combineReducers }` and `{ createStore }`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?